# Is there any way to keep constructions and non-inventory items from server 1.1 worlds in newer server versions?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, server-administration

I've been running a Minecraft server for a while and never had any problems with server upgrades before, up to and including version 1.1. Now I'm testing 1.2.x, and although I always spawn in the location where my home used to be, the world there is completely different. What am I missing?

Comment: It's a bit weird. Are you running a vanilla server or a bukkit one?

Comment: Vanilla.  I'm trying to avoid using bukkit if possible.  Although I'm starting to understand why most server admins have given up and are running bukkit.  Why are the vanilla server tools so awful/nonexistent?

Comment: Well, because Minecraft doesn't support mods as is. Bukkit and MCP are possible because Java is somewhat decompilable and mods and other tools can be added. However, this doesn't explain why your map is "resetting". When you update Minecraft, do you overwrite the file in the same directory, or you start over in a new one?

Comment: I just plop the new server JAR into the same folder.  If I put it in a new folder, presumably I would then also need to copy the 'world' subfolder from the old folder to the new one, right?

Comment: Yeah, that's what you would have to do. I don't really know what's going on. Maybe you could try loading your map with MCEdit and see if it's not just a matter of spawn point acting funny.

Comment: Not sure, but have you considered running the standard Minecraft client to update your 1.1 map into the 1.2 Anvil format, then uploading that to the server?  I am not sure if it can or will convert for you.

Comment: @Zoredache: Tried it.  Copied the world folder to the single player data saves folder but the game doesn't even list it, so there's no way to load it.

Comment: @Allov: I'll try MCEdit.

Comment: @Allov: Works okay in MCEdit.  I'm able to open the world I copied from the server folder to the single player saves folder, and the world looks fine, along with my player, spawnpoint and all my stuff.  This world isn't even listed in the Minecraft single player world list.  Any idea what I can do from here?

Comment: Yep, I'm out of solution =( Maybe you could zip it and put it on a public dropbox so I could try to load it maybe.

Comment: Fixed it!  Here's what I did: Copied 'world' folder from server folder to single player 'saves' folder. Opened the world from the 'saves' folder in MCEdit.  Opened the 'World Info' dialog in MCEdit (Ctrl-I), then ran the 'Repair regions' tool. Saved the world. Ran the most recent Minecraft client, and the world appeared in the world list (yay!) but said that it needed to be converted. Opened the world in single player mode from there and it converted, saying 'Converting to Anvil'. Copied the world back to the server folder and ran it in multiplayer mode. Everything was back to normal!

Comment: Will do. It just feels kinda weird to do that.

Comment: Did that preserve all player inventories and locations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resolved. Here's what I did: Copied the 'world' folder from the server folder to single player 'saves' folder. Opened the world from the 'saves' folder in MCEdit. Opened the 'World Info' dialog in MCEdit (Ctrl-I), then ran the 'Repair regions' tool. Saved the world. Ran the most recent Minecraft client, and the world appeared in the world list, but said that it needed to be converted. Opened the world in single player mode from there and it converted, saying 'Converting to Anvil'. Copied the world back to the server folder and ran it in multiplayer mode. Everything was back to normal!